# Using "though" with "or"

Tags: grammar

> Either they were friends or lovers, it's always just the two of them.

> Though friends or lovers, it's always just the two of them.

I was wondering if both sentences mean the same thing, or does each one mean a completely different thing, and which one is more suitable in this context.

Also I'd like to know more about the usage of "though" & words of the same "family".

Comment: No, the second one doesn't make sense.  Generally speaking you can't change lots of words in a sentence and expect it to have identical meaning.

Answer (score 1):

No, the two sentences do not have the same meaning. The first needs a couple of corrections, and I suggest *They are either friends or lovers; it's always just the two of them*. This would mean that they are always together on their own and I have deduced that they are either friends of lovers. The second would mean that they are always together on their own, and that this is unusual because they are friends or lovers.

*Though* and *although* usually indicate that two things are in some way contrary to one another. *Though the light was not bright, there was enough to see by*. (Negative then positive).  *Though I was sick I did not ring work to let them know.* (Contrary as a sick person is expected to ring work).

Answer (score 0):

No, your sentences do not mean the same thing.

The first one says that two people are always together, so they must be either good friends or lovers. (I'm not sure why you used *were* rather than *are*.)

The second sentence doesn't make sense. We use *though* to refer to a fact that makes something *less* likely.

> Though they are either friends or lovers, they are not often seen together in public.

> I recognised him at once even though I had not seen him for ten years.

Comment: In that case, can I rewrite the second sentence using "no matter" or "even"? Would it still convey the same meaning?

Comment: Using "whether" instead of "though" in the second sentence would make better sense.

Comment: _No matter_ or _even_  would still convey a wrong meaning. People don't spend time together _even though_ they are friends!